# How to list directory hierarchy in GtkTreeView widget?

Tags: python, pygtk, gtktreeview

I am trying to generate a hierarchical directory listing in pyGTK.

Currently, I have this following directory tree:

```
/root
    folderA
        - subdirA
            - subA.py
        - a.py

    folderB
        - b.py
```

I have written a function that -almost- seem to work:

```
def go(root, piter=None):

    for filename in os.listdir(root):
        isdir = os.path.isdir(os.path.join(root, filename))
        piter = self.treestore.append(piter, [filename])    

        if isdir == True:
            go(os.path.join(root, filename), piter)
```

This is what i get when i run the app:
[image]

I also think my function is inefficient and that i should be using os.walk(), since it already exists for such purpose.

How can I, and what is the proper/most efficient way of generating a directory tree with pyGTK?

**---edit----**
the block of code i ended up using, that works, is:

```
parents = {}
        for dir, dirs, files in os.walk(root):
            for subdir in dirs:
                parents[os.path.join(dir, subdir)] = self.treestore.append(parents.get(dir, None), [subdir])
            for item in files:
                self.treestore.append(parents.get(dir, None), [item])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the performance, [this is a FAQ](http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=show&file=faq13.043.htp).
About your algorithm: when you reach `subdirA` `piter` points to `subdirA`, at the next iteration when you reach `a.py` `piter` still points to `subdirA`.

As you said, use `os.walk`.