# Show directories and files using GtkTreeView

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, gtktreeview

Having the following base code for walking a directory I would like to fill a GtkTreeView with the directory and files information to the user:

```
import os
for (path, dirs, files) in os.walk("/etc"):
    print path, dirs, files
```

C code is also welcome since it is easy to translate to pygtk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551147/how-to-list-directory-hierarchy-in-pygtk-treeview-widget) question.

The question was funnily the other way around: how to get the directory structure which can then be filled into the `TreeView`.